# CKEditor : Slowness with my Plugin to insert html when a key was pressed

Tags: ckeditor

this is a part of my plugin code wich replace the space caracter by a symbol

```
editor.on( 'key', function( event ) {
    if ( editor.mode != 'wysiwyg' )
        return;

    if(event.data.keyCode == 32)
    {
         editor.insertHtml("&#183;");
         event.cancel();
    }
});
```

This plugin works, my symbol is displayed when i press the space bar. But if i press the space bar multiple times, only the first symbol is displayed. I need to wait 1 or 2 secondes before i can press space bar again to display another symbol. If i press another key, i have no problem.

Do anyone has a explanation ?
Thanks

Comment: Can you create a simple JSFiddle on which we can test it?

Comment: I create a JSFiddle as you request https://jsfiddle.net/tvan7vrh/ and it works !!
So my problem is somewhere else....